# The size of output binary is smaller by using gcc rather than g++

Tags: c++, c, arm

I'm migrating my project from C to C++ and today I noticed something strange. I have two almost the same (the only difference is extern keyword in .cpp) main files (created for compilation testing purpose). The first one is main.c and the second one is main.cpp.

The source code of these files you can find below. I'm using libopencm3, which is compiled to the static library, and then it is linked anywhere it is needed. So what is the problem? In the scenario where I compile my project using main.c (using gcc), the output binary is much more smaller than the output binary produced by compiling using main.cpp (using g++). I can't figure out what causes this issue?

The code is compiled for the STM32F1C8T6 target.

//main.c

```
#include <libopencm3/stm32/rcc.h>

static void rcc_setup()
{
  //Clock setup
  rcc_clock_setup_in_hse_8mhz_out_72mhz();

  //Peripherals clock
  rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_GPIOA);
  rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_GPIOB); 
}

int main()
{
  rcc_setup();

  while(1)
  {

  }
}
```

//main.cpp

```
extern "C" { 
  #include <libopencm3/stm32/rcc.h>
}

static void rcc_setup()
{
  //Clock setup
  rcc_clock_setup_in_hse_8mhz_out_72mhz();

  //Peripherals clock
  rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_GPIOA);
  rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_GPIOB); 
}

int main()
{
  rcc_setup();

  while(1)
  {

  }
}
```

The structure of my project looks basically like:

```
- root
  CMakeLists.txt
  - lib
    - libopencm3
  - src 
    - app
      CMakeLists.txt
      - inc 
      - src
        - main.c
        - main.cpp
```

Here is my root CMakeFile.txt. I think it is the most important because it contains compilation flags, etc. There are also some other things within it, like port dirs, port.cmake etc, but these are not important in this case, so please just ignore them.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(stm32-template)

# COMPILER JUST TEMPORARY TODO: REMOVE!!!
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER "/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++")

# CMAKE MODULES
include(${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake)

# GENERAL PATHS 
set(PORT_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/port/${PORT})

# PORT CONFIGURATIOM 
include(${PORT_DIR}/port.cmake)

# COMPILER CONFIGURATION
set(COMPILER_CXX_FLAGS "-fno-use-cxa-atexit -Os")
set(COMPILER_FLAGS "-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -O0 -DNDEBUG -Werror")
set(LINKER_FLAGS "-nostartfiles -specs=nano.specs -specs=nosys.specs --static -ggdb3 -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--start-group -lc -lgcc -lnosys -Wl,--end-group -Wl,-Map=output.map -T ${LD_SCRIPT}")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${COMPILER_FLAGS} ")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${COMPILER_CXX_FLAGS} ${COMPILER_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${LINKER_FLAGS}")

# LIBRARIES 
set(LIBOPENCM3_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libopencm3)
set(LIBOPENCM3_INCLUDE ${LIBOPENCM3_PATH}/include)
set(LIBOPENCM3_BIN ${LIBOPENCM3_PATH}/lib/libopencm3_${MCU_FAMILY}.a)
ExternalProject_Add(libopencm3
    SOURCE_DIR "${LIBOPENCM3_PATH}"
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE true
    DOWNLOAD_COMMAND ""
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND make
)

# ADD LIBRARY INCLUDES 
include_directories(${LIBOPENCM3_INCLUDE})

# SUBDIRECTORIS 
add_subdirectory(src)

# CUSTOM COMMANDS 
add_custom_target(flash
  COMMAND JLinkExe -device STM32F103C8 -If SWD -Speed 1000 -CommandFile tools/jlink/FlashCommand.jlink
  COMMENT "asd"

  #DEPENDS {EXE_NAME}
)
```

Comment: The C standard library can lean a lot more on the OS for implementations, but the C++ standard library has a lot of things it has to have code for that aren't in the OS. Streams and locale stuff mostly.

Comment: Someone just before, posted the comment that suggested to use "-fno-exceptions", and it helped. The size of output binary is the same no matter I  use main.cpp or main.c. I totally forgot about this flag.

Comment: @MooingDuck what OS? it is bare metal

Comment: Yes it is bare metal. I didn't point it in the question, but it is of course kinda important.

Comment: You can also look at the output of `objdump` to see what's included. It will output the contents of an executable image. It can even disassemble it if you use -S.

Comment: And when you say binary what do you mean the elf output from the toolchain or after you do the equivalent of objdump -O binary (depending on your toolchain of course as to how you do this)?

Comment: By size of binary I mean, the output of size command on my .elf file, and especially the size of .text section.

Answer (score 4):

The C++ language has a much larger runtime than the C language (because of things like exceptions, RTTI, `<iostream>`, `<thread>`, and so forth).

When you link an application statically, you link in the entire language runtime, or at least those parts that are referenced somewhere in your code, including objects of static and thread-local storage duration in headers you pull in (eg. std::cout).  Most desktop applications don't see this because it tends to be in DSOs.

Because of language interop, you'll find a good deal of the C++ runtime is actually in your system libc.  That includes exception handling and unwinding. If you see symbols like __cxa_* and *Unwind** that's what's going on.